# how to pass FormData from react to express server to save the data in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am using formdata and axios.post method to send the data to the server,
i am also using express.json() and express.urlencoded({extended:false}), but no data passing, although payload is showing the formdata. what to do... ?
here is my code
react code:

```
const submit = async(e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     if(validate()){
         const url = 'http://localhost:5000/users/adduser'
         const formdata = new FormData();
         if(input.myimage===""){
             formdata.append("image",null)
         }
         else{
            formdata.append("image",input.myimage.name)
         }
         formdata.append("fname",input.fname)
         formdata.append("lname",input.lname)
         formdata.append("gender",input.gender)
         formdata.append("t_no",input.tnumber)
         formdata.append("join_date",input.jdate)
         formdata.append("address",input.address)
         formdata.append("confirm_date",input.cdate)
         formdata.append("birthdate",input.dob)
         formdata.append("email",input.email)
         formdata.append("passport",input.passport)
         formdata.append("phone",input.phone)
         try{
             console.log("this is try")
             const response = await Axios.post(url,formdata)
             console.log(response);
         }
         catch(err)
         {
             console.log(err)
         }
     }
 }
```

on Server Side:
app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.port || 5000;
const path = require("path");
const router = require("./router/router");
const cors = require("cors")
require("./connection/database")

app.use('/public',express.static('public'));

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : false, }));

app.use(cors());

app.use("/users",router);

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server is running at port - ${PORT}`)
})
```

router.js:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mycontrol = require("../controller/mycontrolls");


router.use(express.json())
router.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : false, }));

router.get("/", (req,res)=>{
   // res.json({message:"This is my Homepage"})
   console.log("home");
});

router.post("/adduser", mycontrol.adduser)

module.exports = router;
```

mycontroll.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const Data = require("../models/Userschema")

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : false, }));

const adduser = async(req,res) => {
    if(req.body.length === 0){
       console.log("no data passed"); 
    }
    else{
    console.log("I am in adduser else");    
    console.log(req.body);
    const {fname,lname,gender,t_no,join_date,address,confirm_date,birthdate,email,passport,phone,image} = req.body;
    const data = new Data({fname,lname,gender,t_no,join_date,address,confirm_date,birthdate,email,passport,phone,image})
    const result = await data.save();
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({message:"passed"})
    }
};
module.exports = {adduser}
```

I am getting ok response i.e my request succesfully processed, but form data is not presend on the server, this is what i get in my node console:

```
I am in adduser else
{}
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62837f38fe3be21335e88b07"),
  createdAt: 2022-05-17T10:55:52.762Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-05-17T10:55:52.762Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

id created by mongodb, timestamp also created, but the data that is passed from formdata is empty.

Give me the solution please.

Comment: Don't you need to pass `headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}` for `axios` call?

Comment: Use `multer` middleware instead of `express.urlencoded`.  http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html

Comment: #mchowdam ,,  I already tried headers, but not working.

Comment: #Dmitriy use of multer works for me,, thanks